# New DM running a game with also new players have some questions!

Tags: dnd-5e, new-players, new-gm

Me and my siblings(all in our 20s) are going to try and get into DnD. Well more like I'm trying to get into DnD and I'm bringing my siblings into it too. Since I'm the one that's the most into it I figured I should do the Dungeon Mastering. We're going to do the Lost Mine of Phandelver adventure and as I'm reading through it I have a few questions I have that I would love some advice on.

Ok so first, should I be studying all 4 parts for our first session or is it time better spent to only worry about the first part or so since we won't be getting further than that I'm guessing in our first play session?

As I'm reading through the adventure I feel like there's going to be a lot of situations where players that have played D&D know what to look for and know their options for roll checks and what not, but I feel as brand new players my adventurers won't know that they can inspect the dead horses or do a sweep and see the goblins waiting for them when they're by the cave and so forth. Should I be trying to point out their options or just let them do them?

I liked the idea of having the adventurers take part in the storytelling by having them come up with how they knew the two guys that get kidnapped, what are some other ways I can involve them with the storyetlling to try and get them more into the roleplaying? And furthermore what are some ways I can help them get into roleplaying in general?

Lastly D&D is completely a new type of thing for us, I mean we play video games and the like but pen and paper rpg where we have to create and roleplay is new. How can I help create an environment that encourages getting out of our comfort zone and such? 
Thanks for any help, I appreciate it!

Comment: Hello and welcome to RPG.SE.  We're a focused question and answer site, so "I need general tips" isn't really in scope, though we do have questions aimed at new gms and players (you can find them through the tags you added to the question). I think you'll also find many of your sub-questions we have dedicated Q&As for already, check around. Then as you have single specific questions, ask them individually.

Comment: I think that the questions are VERY broad, and need to be condensed in scope. The ones that are connected can stand alone as one question, the other topics, more questions.

Comment: Alright I will do that, thanks! I apologize for not perusing these dedicated Q&As beforehand.